# SQL - How to return a count of 0

Tags: mysql, sql-server, reporting-services, count, ssrs-2008

Say I have a table, and one of the column is `GroupName`. Each row can have one of three values for this column: A, B, or C. If I want to query how many objects of each group are in my database, I can run something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c, GroupName
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY GroupName
```

Here's my problem: if, for example, I have 100 objects in the table, and 75 are in A 25 in B and 0 in C, if I run this query it will return this:

```
GroupName    c
--------------
A           75
B           25
```

However, I am trying to use this query to populate an SSRS table to show the amounts, and this table needs to show all *possible* groups, not just the ones actually used. In this example, I would still need a third row in my table for C. If the row was there I know how to put in a 0, eg `=IIf(Fields!c.Value = Nothing, "0", Fields!c.Value)`, but in the above example it doesn't even create a row. How can I assure that a row will be created for each value, even if said value is not used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To even know you have a group C, that must be in one of your tables, so you'll need to do something like this:

```
select X.c, G.GroupName
from 
groups G
outer apply (
  SELECT COUNT(*) c, GroupName
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY GroupName
) X on X.GroupName = G.GroupName
```

Comment: outer apply can filter using WHERE in the subquery.. or you should just use LEFT JOIN instead

Comment: @thnkwthprtls we must have a different compiler :)